# use preg_replace with named array

Tags: php, preg-replace

i have a problem with preg_replace: Because of multilanguage i have created an array for every value in the date() function:

```
$a = array( "d" => "19", "l" => "Saturday", "F" => "October", "Y" => "", ...);
```

now i want to have an string like `$s = "{l}, the {d}. of {F} {Y}";`

My question is, how can i use preg_replace or sth to replace the expressions in brackets with the values of my array? My problem is that i don't know how to get `$a["Y"]` based on the char within the { } brackets.

Comment: Quite easily. How about show us what you've done first?

Answer (score 1):

check serialize or json_encode , then replace strings.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Answer (score 1):

This is possible using [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
$a = array( "d" => "19", "l" => "Saturday", "F" => "October" , "Y" => "");
$s = "{l}, the {d}. of {F} {Y}";

function callback($m) {
    global $a;
    return $a[$m[1]];
}

echo preg_replace_callback("/\{(.)\}/", "callback", $s);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're basically doing string replacement; regular expressions are quite overkill here. I would create a function like so

```
function insertTokens($string, $values)
{
    foreach ($values as $key => $value)
    {
        $string = str_replace('{'.$key.'}', $value);
    }
    return $string;
}

$newString = insertTokens($s, $a);
```